# Datatables fnSort advise

Tags: javascript, datatables

Looking for some help as to where to place fnSort with this datatables code to make the default sort the second column as opposed to the first. I have:

```
dataClones['keyword_table_<?php echo ceil($countCallsCounter/7); ?>']=document.getElementById('keyword_table_<?php echo ceil($countCallsCounter/7); ?>').cloneNode(true);

    $('#keyword_table_<?php echo ceil($countCallsCounter/7); ?>').dataTable( {
    //"sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sDom":"<<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }

} 
);
```

I know I need to add http://datatables.net/api#fnSort but I am not overly familiar with JS so after some quick help if possible.

Thanks

Comment: [Bhavesh Kidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15135818) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66023186) saying "This link may be work for you for old jquery datatable https://legacy.datatables.net/ref"

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is set a variable = to the $(selector).datatable() call. Then you can call the variable.fnSort().

```
var oTable; // Make sure this is within scope of your function, or where you want to execute the sort.

dataClones['keyword_table_<?php echo ceil($countCallsCounter/7); ?>']=document.getElementById('keyword_table_<?php echo ceil($countCallsCounter/7); ?>').cloneNode(true);

    oTable = $('#keyword_table_<?php echo ceil($countCallsCounter/7); ?>').dataTable( {
    //"sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sDom":"<<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }

} 
);

function onSort(){
    oTable.fnSort([0,'asc']);
}
```

Also if you know the column you want to sort by on initialize of the datatable you could:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]
} );
```

http://datatables.net/api#fnSort
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html